# Get inner elements from XML file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an XML file with table tennis rules I want to parse to HTML with JavaScript. Heres the XML:

```
<rulesection>
        <sectiontitle>A let</sectiontitle>
        <rule>
            <point>2.09.01</point>
            <description>
                The rally shall be a let
            </description>
        <subrule>
            <point>2.09.01.01</point>
            <description>
                if in service the ball, in passing over or around the net assembly, touches it, provided the service is otherwise correct or the ball is obstructed by the receiver or his or her partner;
            </description>
        </subrule>
</rule>
</rulesection>
```

I have some JavaScript code so I can get the sectiontitle, point and description. Unfortunately I can´t seem to get the subrules and Google wont help me with this. With the code I have now I only get the first rule of every rulesection.

```
    <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "fuckrules.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;


var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rulesection");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("sectiontitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("point")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
</script>
```

I have tried to use multiple for-loops but I still cant get the points and descriptions of the subrules inside a rule. If anyone could give me some pointers that would be really helpful :)

Comment: The XML is not well-formed, and it has only one `rule` element.

Comment: It still has only one `rule` element, so what does the remark “I only get the first rule of every rulesection” mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind introducing jQuery into your project, this is dirt simple.

Assume your XML was loaded into a `rules` variable:

```
// iterate over each rulesection
rules.each(function(idx) {
    var s = jQuery(this); // s now refers to a single rulesection node
    var blurp = jQuery('<section class="rulesection" />'); 
    // build up blurp to have the elements you need
    blurp.append('<h1 class="title">' + jQuery('sectiontitle', s).text() + '</h1>');
    // note use of second param to limit matches to 's' node
    // (you can do another .each() on the rules / subrules)
    jQuery('subrule', s).each(function (idx) {
        var sr = jQuery(this); // is the first subrule node
        // do stuff with it...
    });

    // add to the container
    jQuery('#rules').append(blurp);
});
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tx2fr132/5/

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I dont have time to start to learn jQuery right now.